# How Can I change a single line in a file of my plugin and commit to WordPress plugin repo without creating a new version?

Tags: wordpress, svn, tortoisesvn

It's a stupid question but I'm not able to find the answer by myself...
I've a plugin in wordpress.org repository and I've realized that I need to add a single line to a css file.
I'm wondering if it's possible do this change without create a new version for just a minor change (so it's not important if the update will come to the users only with the next update). I use TortoiseSVN.
What's your thoughts?
Thank you

I stll didn't anything because I know it's easy to break things :)

Comment: Yes, you can make changes without having to update your plugin's version number.

Comment: Can you explain the procedure? Do I have to change the code both in trunk and in the last tag? I have to commit? I'm not sure...

Comment: Well, if all you're going to change is a single line of code (eg. a CSS rule) then yeah you'd make that change in `trunk` and in the last tag so people downloading the latest version of your plugin or those who are upgrading to it get that change too.

Comment: Ideally though you should push a new release whenever you're trying to fix something, but if it's nothing urgent / site-breaking I guess you could just commit your changes and not release a new update.

Comment: @cabrerahector, thank you for your clarification. If you post it as an answer I can choose it as solution :)

Comment: The term "version" does not have a meaning in Subversion. Any change to the repository will result in a new *revision* and you cannot prevent that. You can, however, change tags and branches as explained by cabrerhector. So, it depends on what "version" means for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make changes to your plugin without needing to release a new version. Just change whatever needs changing in `trunk` and/or a specific tag and that's it.

Ideally though you should push a new release whenever you're trying to fix something, but if it's nothing urgent / site-breaking I guess you could just commit your changes and not release a new update.